# How to prove that $\beta X$ is the only H-compactification of $l^2$?

Tags: general-topology, hilbert-spaces, compactness, compactification

H-compactification is defined as such compactification that all autohomeomorphisms on the original space can be continuously extended to the compactification. (Sometimes H-compactifications are called "topological compactifications" too).

For example $\mathbb{R}^n$ has for $n \geq 2$ only two topological compactifications: $\alpha \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\beta \mathbb{R}^n$.

My guess is that $l^2$space would have only $\beta l^2$ as its topological compactification, as $\alpha l^2$ is impossible (since $l^2$ is not locally compact).

What do you think about this and do you know how to prove that?

**Disclaimer:** I am assuming Hausdorff compactifications (so the spaces are Tychonoff).

**Notation**: $\alpha$... ALexandroff one-point compactficiation, $\beta$... Stone-Čech compactification.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130240/discussion-on-question-by-tereza-tizkova-how-to-prove-that-beta-x-is-the-only).