# How does existence of complemented subspace imply extending automorphisms?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, inner-products

Suppose we have an inner space $X$ with a complemented finite-dimensional subspace $M$. Denote the complement by $N$.

My questions are:

**1.** If $X$ is infinite-dimensional and $M$ is finite-dimensional, does that mean $N$ is infinite-dimensional?

**2.** If $X$ has a complemented subspace, does that imply that any autohomeomorphism of a finite-dimensional subspace extends to an autohomeomorphism of the whole $X$?

I have seen the "2." in *tomasz*´s comments under [one of my previous questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4261787/how-to-prove-that-beta-x-is-the-only-h-compactification-of-l2?noredirect=1#comment8869976_4261787), that´s why I am interested whether this holds generally and why.

Thank you for any insights.

Comment: 1: of course; otherwise $X$ would be finite-dimensional. 2. Yes for linear autohomeomorphisms by simple linear algebra, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **1.** If $X$ is infinite-dimensional and $M$ is finite-dimensional, does that mean $N$ is infinite-dimensional?

Yes. In general, if $X=M\oplus N$ then $\dim X=\dim M+\dim N$ and so $X$ being infinite dimensional implies that one of $M,N$ has to be infinite dimensional as well.

> **2.** If $X$ has a complemented subspace, does that imply that any autohomeomorphism of a finite-dimensional subspace extends to an autohomeomorphism of the whole $X$?

Yes. So first of all, a linear subspace $M\subseteq X$ has a complement $N$, if $N\subseteq X$ is a linear subspace such that $X\simeq M\oplus N$ and the isomorphism is both linear and a homeomorphism. WLOG we can assume that $X=M\oplus N$. Let $f:M\to M$ be an autohomeomorphism. Then it extends to $F:X\to X$ via $F(a,b):=(f(a),b)$ which is an autohomeomorphism as well. Note that dimensions here don't matter.

Comment: Why is the $F$ defined this way? Is the $a$ from $M$ and $b$ from $N$, where $b$ is just mapped into itself? How is mapping such pairs correctly defined homeomorphism?

Comment: @TerezaTizkova I'm not sure I understand your question. $F$ is defined this way because I defined it this way. Yes, $a\in M$ and $b\in N$. We are dealing with a product of spaces here. The mapping is a homeomorphism because its inverse is $(a,b)\mapsto (f^{-1}(a),b)$.

Comment: Thanks, I just wasnt sure.